# Adding Guzzle For Mailgun in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5, guzzle, mailgun

I want to use the Mailgun service in Laravel 5. This requires Guzzle 5 to be installed. I've added the following to composer.json, and installed it:

```
"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~5.0"
```

However, my app is giving me this error:

*FatalErrorException in MailgunTransport.php line 121:
Class 'GuzzleHttp\Client' not found*

I've ran composer dump-autoload. What am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: Did you check if the package is in the vendor folder? Are you running or local host or do you have box? If so, did the changes get pushed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve this by using:

```
    "laravel/framework": "5.0.16",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "5.2",
```

composer update

and that is all.

Answer (score 1):

`composer install` installs the packages (including exact versions) listed in `composer.lock`. When adding a new package or changing the version requirements, you need `composer update` (or you can use `composer require`) as the new package isn't in the lock file yet.

Running `composer install` when the `composer.json` has been updated since the last update/require should generate a warning saying `Warning: The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in composer.json, you may be getting outdated dependencies, run update to update them.`